# Не могу переписать запрос по кол-ву событий по вузам

Tags: sql

Всем привет, собрал информацию по тем объектам которые мне нужны, но у меня очень малый опыт для правильного формирования финального запроса, ранее этот запрос брал данные из 2х id, сейчас я его максимально поправил для 1 id, ранее считался запрос по кол-ву [EventId], а сейчас я не могу понять как мне считать количество мероприятий по ВУЗам

````
SELECT
    p.[ProjectTypeId] as pType
    ,[Системная информация о респонденте].[ВУЗ_21] 
    ,[Дата заполнения].[Дата заполнения_22] AS [Дата начала события]
    ,[Тип мероприятия].[Тип мероприятия] -- тут был [Тип международного взаимодействия].[EventId]
    ,p.[Id] as pId
FROM [CaseMap].[Projects] p

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        pvb.[ProjectId]
        ,b.[B60378EC-B340-EE11-96E0-F5287361F2E3] as [Дата заполнения_22]   --Tag:dateFilling
        FROM [DataBlocks].[Block_AA0378EC-B340-EE11-96E0-F5287361F2E3] as b
    LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[ProjectVisualBlocks] as pvb on pvb.[Id] = b.[ProjectVisualBlockId]
) AS [Дата заполнения] on [Дата заполнения].[ProjectId] = p.[Id]

-------- Системная информация о респонденте --------

JOIN (
    SELECT
        pvb.[ProjectId]
        ,[Нет данных по мероприятиям_26].[Name] as [Нет данных по мероприятиям_26]
        ,b.[98C50C68-A045-EE11-96E0-F5287361F2E3] as [ВУЗ_21]
        ,[Нет данных по мероприятиям].Name as [Нет данных по мероприятиям]
        FROM [DataBlocks].[Block_AA0378EC-B340-EE11-96E0-F5287361F2E3] as b
    LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[ProjectVisualBlocks] as pvb on pvb.[Id] = b.[ProjectVisualBlockId]
    LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[UserDefinedDictionaryItems] as [Нет данных по мероприятиям_26] on [Нет данных по мероприятиям_26].[Id]=b.[C6118C24-BF40-EE11-96E0-F5287361F2E3]
        LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[UserDefinedDictionaryItems] as [Нет данных по мероприятиям]  on [Нет данных по мероприятиям].Id=b.[c6118c24-bf40-ee11-96e0-f5287361f2e3]
    JOIN (
            SELECT
                pvb.[ProjectId]
                ,[Вид организации_142].[Name] as [Вид организации_142] 
                FROM [DataBlocks].[Block_69155C5C-1347-EE11-96E0-F5287361F2E3] as b
            LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[ProjectVisualBlocks] as pvb on pvb.[Id] = b.[ProjectVisualBlockId]
            LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[UserDefinedDictionaryItems] as [Вид организации_142] on [Вид организации_142].[Id]=b.[EEE47DAF-1947-EE11-96E0-F5287361F2E3]
    ) AS [Вид организации] on [Вид организации].[ProjectId] = b.[98C50C68-A045-EE11-96E0-F5287361F2E3]


) AS [Системная информация о респонденте] on [Системная информация о респонденте].[ProjectId] = p.[Id] and [Системная информация о респонденте].[Нет данных по мероприятиям_26] in (N'Начать',N'Завершить')

-- Тип мероприятия ИСПРАВЛЕНО 08.12 id block + idfield
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                pvb.ProjectId                                               AS project_id,
                uddi_international_type_1.Name                              AS [Тип мероприятия]
                FROM DataBlocks.[Block_a629b83f-e494-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] AS [Тип мероприятия]
                LEFT JOIN CaseMap.ProjectVisualBlocks                       AS pvb
                          ON [Тип мероприятия].ProjectVisualBlockId = pvb.Id
                LEFT JOIN CaseMap.UserDefinedDictionaryItems                AS uddi_international_type_1
                                                        ON [Тип мероприятия].[9ca31665-e494-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] =
                                                           uddi_international_type_1.Id) AS i_t ON i_t.project_id = p.[Id]

    -------- Тип международного взаимодействия состоявшегося события --------
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            pvb.[ProjectId]
            ,[Тип международного взаимодействия состоявшегося события_322].[Name] as [Тип международного взаимодействия состоявшегося события_322] 
--          ,LEFT([Тип международного взаимодействия состоявшегося события_322].[Name], 1) as [EventId]
            FROM [DataBlocks].[Block_d3414069-e394-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] as b
        LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[ProjectVisualBlocks] as pvb on pvb.[Id] = b.[ProjectVisualBlockId]
        LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[UserDefinedDictionaryItems] as [Тип международного взаимодействия состоявшегося события_322] on [Тип международного взаимодействия состоявшегося события_322].[Id]=b.[9da31665-e494-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989]
    ) AS [Тип международного взаимодействия состоявшегося события] on [Тип международного взаимодействия состоявшегося события].[ProjectId] = p.[Id]

-- 1. Информация по исходящей академической мобильности

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        pvb.[ProjectId]
        ,b.[0e424069-e394-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] as [Дата начала_240] 
        FROM [DataBlocks].[Block_d4414069-e394-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] as b
    LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[ProjectVisualBlocks] as pvb on pvb.[Id] = b.[ProjectVisualBlockId]
) AS [1. Информация по исходящей академической мобильности] on [1. Информация по исходящей академической мобильности].[ProjectId] = p.[Id]

-- 2. Инфо по програмее Входящая академическая мобильность

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        pvb.[ProjectId]
        ,b.[22424069-e394-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] as [Дата начала программы (Вх.)_260] 
        FROM [DataBlocks].[Block_d5414069-e394-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] as b
    LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[ProjectVisualBlocks] as pvb on pvb.[Id] = b.[ProjectVisualBlockId]
) AS [2. Инфо по програмее Входящая академическая мобильность] on [2. Инфо по програмее Входящая академическая мобильность].[ProjectId] = p.[Id]

-- 3. Инфо по совместным проектам (долгосрочные)

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        pvb.[ProjectId]
        ,b.[32424069-e394-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] as [Дата начала программы (Исх.)_276] 
        FROM [DataBlocks].[Block_d6414069-e394-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] as b
    LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[ProjectVisualBlocks] as pvb on pvb.[Id] = b.[ProjectVisualBlockId]
) AS [3. Инфо по совместным проектам (долгосрочные)] on [3. Инфо по совместным проектам (долгосрочные)].[ProjectId] = p.[Id]

-- 4. Инфо по совместным мероприятиям

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        pvb.[ProjectId]
        ,b.[43424069-e394-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] as [Дата начала  проекта_293] 
        FROM [DataBlocks].[Block_d7414069-e394-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989] as b
    LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[ProjectVisualBlocks] as pvb on pvb.[Id] = b.[ProjectVisualBlockId]
) AS [4. Инфо по совместным мероприятиям] on [4. Инфо по совместным мероприятиям].[ProjectId] = p.[Id]

WHERE p.IsDeleted=0 and p.IsArchive=0 and p.ProjectTypeId = '0e9d722e-4294-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989'
and [Системная информация о респонденте].[Нет данных по мероприятиям]<>N'Завершить'
) t1

SELECT * INTO #tmp2 FROM(
SELECT
    p.Name as [Название]
    ,[Запланированные события].[Всего] as [Запланированные события]
    ,[Состоявшиеся события].[Всего] as [Состоявшиеся события]
FROM [CaseMap].[Projects] p

-------- Вид организации --------

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        pvb.[ProjectId]
        ,[Вид организации_142].[Name] as [Вид организации_142] 
        FROM [DataBlocks].[Block_69155C5C-1347-EE11-96E0-F5287361F2E3] as b
    LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[ProjectVisualBlocks] as pvb on pvb.[Id] = b.[ProjectVisualBlockId]
    LEFT JOIN [CaseMap].[UserDefinedDictionaryItems] as [Вид организации_142] on [Вид организации_142].[Id]=b.[EEE47DAF-1947-EE11-96E0-F5287361F2E3]
) AS [Вид организации] on [Вид организации].[ProjectId] = p.[Id]
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT 
        t.[ВУЗ_21], count(t.[ВУЗ_21]) as [Всего]
        FROM #tmp1 t
    WHERE t.[Дата начала события] is not null and {condition:z_sob} and t.pType='0e9d722e-4294-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989' GROUP BY t.[ВУЗ_21]
) as [Запланированные события] on [Запланированные события].[ВУЗ_21]=p.Id
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT 
        t.[ВУЗ_21], count(t.[ВУЗ_21]) as [Всего]
        FROM #tmp1 t
    WHERE t.[Дата начала события] is not null and {condition:z_sob} and t.pType='0e9d722e-4294-ee11-96e1-fa3cea454989' GROUP BY t.[ВУЗ_21]
) as [Состоявшиеся события] on [Состоявшиеся события].[ВУЗ_21]=p.Id
WHERE [Вид организации].[Вид организации_142]=N'Высшее Учебное Заведение' and {condition:vuz_name}
) t2

SELECT r.[Название], r.[Запланированные события], r.[Состоявшиеся события] FROM(
select
1 as [sort]
,t.[Название]
,ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(nvarchar(max),t.[Запланированные события]),'Данные не поданы') as [Запланированные события]
,ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(nvarchar(max),t.[Состоявшиеся события]),'Данные не поданы') as [Состоявшиеся события]
from #tmp2 t
UNION ALL
SELECT
2 as [sort]
,N'Итого:' as [itog]
,(SELECT TRY_CONVERT(nvarchar(max),ISNULL(sum(t.[Запланированные события]),0)) as [Запланированные события] from #tmp2 t) as [Запланированные события]
,(SELECT TRY_CONVERT(nvarchar(max),ISNULL(sum(t.[Состоявшиеся события]),0)) as [Состоявшиеся события] from #tmp2 t) as [Состоявшиеся события]
)r 
ORDER BY r.sort

{offset}
DROP TABLE #tmp1 
DROP TABLE #tmp}```
````